# knitr's eval = FALSE not working in R Notebook (still runs code)

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

From all the sources I know ([here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/?version=1.1.50&mode=desktop) and [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/r-markdown.html#), for instance), the chunk option `eval = FALSE` in R is supposed to stop the code from running and only display the code in a knitted document. However, the chunks marked with `eval = FALSE` in my Rstudio always run.

I am not what is the best way to display this issue, so I attached a screenshot below:

[image]

the command `plot(cars)` always get evaluated despite the selected option. While `include = FALSE` can prevent the graph from showing the Console suggests that the code was still executed for the multiple times I run the R document.

```
> plot(cars)
> plot(cars)
> plot(cars)
> plot(cars)
> plot(cars)
>
```

**Question**

I have searched for a while but did not see other people have similar issues yet, and was wondering how to prevent the `echo=FALSE` code chunks from running.

**Session Info**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.3 (Sierra)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] qwraps_0.2.2      reshape2_1.4.2    devtools_1.12.0   gridExtra_2.2.1   astsa_1.7        
 [6] pander_0.6.0      vars_1.5-2        lmtest_0.9-35     strucchange_1.5-1 sandwich_2.3-4   
[11] MASS_7.3-45       forecast_7.3      timeDate_3012.100 zoo_1.7-14        urca_1.3-0       
[16] tsDyn_0.9-44      tseries_0.10-37   stringr_1.1.0     lubridate_1.6.0   forcats_0.2.0    
[21] dplyr_0.5.0       purrr_0.2.2       readr_1.0.0       tidyr_0.6.1       tibble_1.2       
[26] ggplot2_2.2.1     tidyverse_1.1.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1          jsonlite_1.2        foreach_1.4.3       modelr_0.1.0        assertthat_0.1     
 [6] highr_0.6           yaml_2.1.14         backports_1.0.5     lattice_0.20-34     quadprog_1.5-5     
[11] digest_0.6.12       rvest_0.3.2         colorspace_1.3-2    htmltools_0.3.5     Matrix_1.2-8       
[16] plyr_1.8.4          psych_1.6.12        broom_0.4.2         haven_1.0.0         bookdown_0.3       
[21] scales_0.4.1        git2r_0.18.0        mgcv_1.8-17         tseriesChaos_0.1-13 withr_1.0.2        
[26] nnet_7.3-12         lazyeval_0.2.0      mnormt_1.5-5        magrittr_1.5        readxl_0.1.1       
[31] memoise_1.0.0       evaluate_0.10       nlme_3.1-131        xml2_1.1.1          foreign_0.8-67     
[36] rsconnect_0.7       tools_3.3.1         hms_0.3             munsell_0.4.3       grid_3.3.1         
[41] iterators_1.0.8     htmlwidgets_0.8     base64enc_0.1-3     labeling_0.3        rmarkdown_1.3      
[46] gtable_0.2.0        codetools_0.2-15    fracdiff_1.4-2      curl_2.3            DBI_0.5-1          
[51] R6_2.2.0            knitr_1.15.1        rprojroot_1.2       stringi_1.1.2       parallel_3.3.1     
[56] Rcpp_0.12.9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are running the chunk as you would run a normal r script (in Rstudio, Run button with the green arrow.)

Instead, click on Preview and you'll get your html_notebook. You'll see it won't show the plot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But then I wonder what's the difference between eval=FALSE and result = "hide", if I want to run the code but hide the result, I can always use the latter. So my impression was always that eval allows you to demonstrate some complex codes that might run forever without having to use the time and memory every time one knits a markdown file...

Comment: I just read your response again and figured out what you meant!